# Service Worker of CRA not kicking in if query/params has a dot (.)

Tags: reactjs, service-worker, create-react-app

I experience a problem with Service Worker of CRA if the query/params consists of a dot (.) For example, https://www.example.com/?q=2.1_something_like_this

The website would not work offline, but if you remove the dot, if will work again.

How do I fix this without changing the parameters or ejecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Old version of CRA causes this issue, after updating, it's working fine.